# Django: Same model with different features?

Tags: python, mysql, django, normalization

Object Model:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(ProfileUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_object = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

Category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

For example I have some categories, like hotels, restaurants etc. So I want for each category to have different features (radio buttons when adding new), but I'm not sure, how to handle it properly. Hotels must have rooms, pool etc. Restaurants must have country kitchen, seats etc. In future I will have and other categories.

**Quesion is:** Which is  the best way (practice) to do this.

**My solution:** To create third table with features and every category to have column `features` and store features separate by comma, but it's not very good solution based on [DB normalization](http://DB%20Normalization.).

Comment: I would suggest reading this article! It might give you a good inspiration for your use case!
`https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [multi-table inheritance](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/django-patterns-model-inheritance/)

You define a base object, and from there you can define different child objects which will share the parent's properties

In your case that would look something like this:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    ...


class Restaurant(Object):
   seats = IntegerField(...)
   reservations = ManyToManyField(...)

class Hotel(Object):
   rooms = IntegerField(...)
   has_pool = BooleanField(...)
```

Django will automatically create relationships and manage the querying for you. To get all restaurants, you can use `Restaurant.objects.all()`, there is a limitation though. When querying `Object.objects.all()`, you will get a list of the `Objects`, not their specific subclass. If I remember correctly, you can access the specific instance through (for instance) `object.restaurant`.

If you do want to get the specific objects, you can look into a library called [Django-polymorphic](https://github.com/bconstantin/django_polymorphic).

Comment: Hmm, looks very nice, but right now, i'm not able to check this solution, so still cannot accept this answer, but you have my upvote for now :)

Comment: Okay, it works fine. One more question, now it works with dropdown (choose category, send AJAX to views.py and depends on param (category) show different form for each category via switch case (if else statement in python)) Is there more clever way to show different forms ?

Comment: Maybe add a form_class field to the different models? Then you can simply call the form from the object, something like `form_class = RestaurantForm`

Comment: Yes, but then every restaurant will have it, there will be a repeat. Also if I want to automate it (If I create links for every category, like now, and call objects for each category, now I should use if statement) ? The major problem is that I cannot separate different categories now (because they don't have unique, like category_id, or something else)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models. You write your base class and put abstract=True in the Meta class. This model will then not be used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child class.

You can then make your `Restaurant` and `Hotel` models inherit from this abstract class. Django will then create two tables with the base fields from the abstract class plus the specific fields from each models.

Comment: Using an abstract base class does not enable you to query all 'Objects' though, right?

Comment: It doesn't, you're right, but was it a requirement of @MorganFreeFarm ?

Comment: I don’t know, just checking ;)

Answer (score 1):

> i will explain this one by one :

[image: schema]

- `category` table contains all categories.
- now there may have some common and unique feature for every category.`features` will have `many to many` relation with `category` table.
  so we create `feature_master` table and we will map it with category table.
- `feature_master` table contains all features.
- `category_feature_map` table is map table(junction table)
- `object` table have all the detail about object and `object_detail` table will contain all the `feature` to particular object

Comment: Thank you about this answer, but from Django development view, I think that solutions above are better :)

Comment: db should be independent of o.r.m. always.  so if in time we want to change the framework ,we will not have to worry about database. db should be independent of orm always